# parsefloat('string' + var) syntax issue

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

I have a string that equals 'Res' described by:

```
ResEmp = drpdwn.id.substring(3,6)
```

If I wanted the following code:

```
parseFloat(AppResYrs.value)
```

to get 'Res' from the ResEmp variable, what syntax would I use?

I've tried `parseFloat('App' + ResEmp + 'Yrs.value')` and `parseFloat(('App' + ResEmp + 'Yrs').value)` and they don't work. Thank you!

Edit: The following code: `alert(ResEmp); alert(parseFloat(AppResYrs.value)); alert(parseFloat('App' + ResEmp + 'Yrs').value);` returns 'Res', '0' and 'undefined'. The first two are correct. I want the last one to return 0 also, because I want it to mean the same thing as the second.

Comment: You should think about using arrays or objects. Constructing variable names from strings is not a really good practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming it's the ID of a DOM element, you'd do;

```
parseFloat(document.getElementById("App" + ResEmp + "Yrs").value);
```

If it's a global object with `value` attribute, you could cheat and do;

```
parseFloat(window["App" + ResEmp + "Yrs"].value));
```

Otherwise you can't access it.